# Is it possible to use in statement for integer inside linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I need to look inside a collection if contains multiple elements.
Can i use in statement?

Example:

```
public class Person
{
   public int Age { get; set; }
}
    
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var person = new List<Person>();
    person.Add(new Person { Age = 1 });
    person.Add(new Person { Age = 5 });
    person.Add(new Person { Age = 2 });
    person.Add(new Person { Age = 3 });

    var selectedPersons = person.Where(x => x.Age in (1, 3, 5));
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume the `in` is meant as you would use it in SQL-where. If you want all `Age` that contain 1, 2 or 3 you would write:

```
var selectedPersons = person.Where(x => new [] {1, 2, 3}.Contains(x.Age));
```

If you want to select all persons that have an Age between 1 and 3 than you would write:

```
var selectedPersons = person.Where (x => x.Age >= 1 && x.Age <= 3);
```

Comment: Ive always wondered, would the compiler optimize the array allocation out of the predicate or would it be wise to declare it outside ourselves?

Comment: Thank you, yes i mean in like sql. I thing that first solution can fit for my needs!